# Bad query performance with multiple and's in select statement

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

Hi I'm using SQL mangement studio 2008R2.

I have a query to get scanids of tblScan where some varbinary(max) fields are null. My query is:

```
select SCANID 
from tblScan 
where scanFileFace is null 
  and scanFileAvatar is null 
  and hair is null
```

When I execute my query in SQL it take a minute and half the first time I run this query.
At my client this gives a timeout exception. If I haven't ran the query 1 time in SQL management studio.

What is the best way to optimize this query? Or is it ok to just increase the timeout in my connection string ?

Edit:

This is my table design:

**SCANID** -    int 
**scanDate** -  datetime     
**scanFileMeasurements** -  varbinary(MAX)   
**MEMBERID** -  int 
**scanFileFace** -  varbinary(MAX)   
**scanFileAvatar** -    varbinary(MAX)   
**Hair** -  varbinary(MAX)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason why it runs faster the second time is likely thanks to query caching :) to understand why your initial query is slow, you'd have to show more info such as current table structure.

Comment: @Jack I added the table design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to employ [materialized view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). In short, it is an indexed view that behaves as a table and changes as underlying data changes, but it does not need to execute select as data is already prepared during CRUD operations on underlying table(s).

```
create view EmptyScans with schemabinding
as
    select SCANID 
      from dbo.tblScan 
     where scanFileFace is null 
       and scanFileAvatar is null 
       and hair is null
GO
create unique clustered index ix_empty_scans on EmptyScans (ScanID)
GO

select scanid 
  from EmptyScans (noexpand)
```

Do not forget to add noexpand hint when you select from materialized view, otherwise it will act as normal view (at least in my experience with Sql Server 2005).

Comment: Nice, just what I needed! Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Please use indexes on scanFileFace ,scanFileAvatar and hair fields.

Create a calculated column that will automatically calculated as the values are changed in target field and create index on this calculated field. I will boost the query performance  a lot.

```
alter table tblScan
add ContentLength as ISNULL(DATALENGTH(scanFileFace ),0) persisted

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblScan_ContentLength] ON [dbo].[tblScan] 
(
    [ContentLength] ASC
)

select scanid from tblScan where ContentLength > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a calculated boolean field with an index is what you want.

When you insert, let the boolean field be your existing condition; when updating you could do this with triggers